# Angular - avoid nested subscriptions by chaining multiple Observables

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, angular-reactive-forms, subscription

I'm trying to refactor my code, since it currently uses several nested subscriptions. I have a basic understanding of RxJS and was already able to rewrite some parts, but now I got stuck and definitely need some help.

I have the following scenario:

1. Get the id of a certain item
2. Obtain all versions of the item
3. Get the details for a specific version. Once you have those, initialize a form
4. For several FormControls we need to watch for value changes
5. In parallel we also need to subscribe to a button click, which is provided by a shared service

This is a simplified version of the initial code:

```
propertiesList = ['prop1', 'prop2', ...]

// 1
this.itemService.currentItem$.subscribe(item => {
      // 2
      this.itemService.getVersions(item .id).subscribe((versionsList: any) => {
        // 3
        this.itemService.getVersionItem(versionsList[versionsList.length - 1].id).subscribe((version: any) => {
          this.version = version
          this.id = this.version.id
          if (this.version.properties) {
            this.formInit()

            // 4
            this.propertiesList.forEach((property: any) => {
              this.form.get(property)?.get('type')?.valueChanges.subscribe(val => {
                if (val === '') {
                  // do something
                } else if (val === 'xxx') {
                  // do something 
                } else {
                  // do something 
                }
              })
              this.form.get(property)?.get('count')?.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
                  // do something 
                }
              )
            })
            // 5
            this.sharedService.buttonClicked$.subscribe((action: any) => {
              if (action.name === 'reset') {
                this.formInit()
              } else if (action.name === 'submit') {
                ...

                this.propertiesList.forEach((property: any) => {
                   // do something
                     ...
                })
              }
            })
          }        
      })
    })
  })
```

And this is what I got so far:

```
this.itemService.currentItem$
      .pipe(
        filter(item => item  !== ''),
        switchMap((item : any) => this.itemService.getVersions(itemService.id)),
        switchMap(versionsList => this.itemService.getVersionItem(versionsList[versionsList.length - 1].id)),
        tap((version) => {
          this.version = version

          this.id = this.version.id
          if (this.version.properties) {
            this.formInit()
          }
        })
```

I am not sure how to handle the whole valueChanges and the button subscription next. I tried using merge and forkJoin, but I either get some errors or the changes are not registered. I'd really appreciate some tips and ideas, because I already spent several days on this and I'm getting kind of desperate.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
// 1
combineLatest([
  this.itemService.currentItem$,
  this.sharedService.buttonClicked$,
]).pipe(
  switchMap(([item, action]) =>
    // 2
    this.itemService.getVersions(item.id).pipe(
      map(versionsList => versionsList[versionsList.length - 1].id),
      switchMap(versionId => this.itemService.getVersionItem(versionId)),
      tap(version => {
        this.version = version;
        this.id = version.id;
        if (this.version.properties) {
          this.formInit();

          // 3
          const valueChanges$ = this.propertiesList.map(property =>
            combineLatest([
              this.form.get(property)?.get('type')?.valueChanges,
              this.form.get(property)?.get('count')?.valueChanges,
            ]).pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
          );

          valueChanges$.forEach(valueChanges =>
            valueChanges.subscribe(([type, count]) => {
              switch (type) {
                case '':
                  // do something
                  break;
                case 'xxx':
                  // do something
                  break;
                default:
                  // do something
              }

              // do something
            })
          );

          // 4
          this.sharedService.buttonClicked$
            .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$))
            .subscribe(action => {
              if (action.name === 'reset') {
                this.formInit();
              } else if (action.name === 'submit') {
                // do something

                this.propertiesList.forEach(property => {
                  // do something
                });
              }
            });
        }
      })
    )
  ),
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe();
```

Unsubscribe from all observables to prevent memory leaks

```
private unsubscribe$ = new Subject();

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.unsubscribe$.next();
  this.unsubscribe$.complete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
propertiesList = ['prop1', 'prop2', ...]

// 1
this.itemService.currentItem$.pipe(
  //2
  switchMap(item => this.itemService.getVersions(item .id)),
  //3
  switchMap((versionsList: any) =>  this.itemService.getVersionItem(versionsList[versionsList.length - 1].id)),
  tap((version) => {
    this.version = version;
    this.id = this.version.id
  })),
  switchMap((version) => {
    if(!this.version.properties) {
      return EMPTY; 
    }

    this.formInit();

    return merge(
      ...this.controlsObservables(), //4
      this.sharedButtonObservable() //5
    )
  }),
  // if you dont want the notifications from the valuesChanges
  // and the buttonClick to cascade down to the subscribe, you can add
  // ignoreElement operator to consume them
  ignoreElements()
}).subscribe();


// map each property to a merge Observable of its controls valueChanges
// and return them in an array
controlsObservables() {
  return this.propertiesList.map((property: any) => {
    const valueChangesObs = [
      this.form.get(property)?.get('type')?.valueChanges.pipe(tap(val =>  /*logic*/ )),
      this.form.get(property)?.get('count')?.valueChanges.pipe(tap(val => /*logic*/ ))
    ].filter(Boolean) // just to remove elements where the get fails to get the control 
    
    return merge(...valueChangesObs);
  });
}

sharedButtonObservable() {
  return this.sharedService.buttonClicked$.pipe(tap((action: any) => /*button logic*/));
}
```

Cheers